# (Ionic) handleNotificationReceived does not get called if the app is killed

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, onesignal, android-push-notification

I am working on an ionic app and I am using onesignal for push notifications.

The problem I am facing is that the `handleNotifiactionRecieved()` does not get triggered upon receiving a push notification when the app is not killed (that is removed from the recent apps). Though it works as expected when the app's running but in the background(not inFocus).

setup code is something like this:

```
if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
        this.oneSignal.startInit('APP_ID');
        this.oneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(this.oneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.None);
        this.openOneSignalMessage();
        this.oneSignal.endInit();
      }
```

my code is something like this:

```
openOneSignalMessage() {
this.oneSignal.handleNotificationReceived().subscribe((data) => {
      this.MsgBody = data.payload.body
      console.log('newMessageOneSignal MsgBody', this.MsgBody);
 });
}
```

> actual result: `handleNotificationReceived()` doesn't get called when the app is not running, that is killed.
>
> expected result: `handleNotificationReceived()` should be called every time a push notification arrives even when the app is not open.

How do I trigger the method every time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for pointing out the issue in the docs. They have been updated with the correct info:

### handleNotificationReceived (builder method)

Sets a notification received handler. Only called if the app is running in the **foreground** at the time the notification was received.

If you want to handle from a killed state, make sure to use the **`handleNotificationOpened`** [method](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/cordova-sdk#section--handlenotificationopened-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but what if the user doesn't click the notification and opens the app directly and the notification itself gets dismissed upon opening the app? what then?

Comment: Unfortunately, the user has to click the notification for it to be handled in that case Saurab

Answer (score 1):

I find this in the doc:

> Sets a notification received handler. Only called if the app is running in the foreground or background at the time the notification was received.

Maybe  your app is not working on background.

Or the problem is you need to call ur function after the startinit  :

```
this.onesignal.startInit("YOUR_APPID")
this.onesignal.handleNotificationReceived()
```

Comment: I have edited the question above, actually i missed to surround the `handleNotificationReceived()` with `openOneSignalMessage()`"{ }.

Comment: As you told i am doing the same. Probably the app is not running in the background after killing it from the recent apps.

Comment: I found this solution https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK/issues/257  hope it can help you.

Comment: the problem is  you can't call `handleNotificationReceived()` if the app is not working on background.

Comment: why is that happening, I mean it is supposed to be running in the background.

Comment: Try this plugin to see  if your plugin work  on background and if not , just activate it :https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

Comment: thanks, I tried this and it actually crashed application saying the app keeps on stopping

Comment: Sry  but I really don't know how help you more , maybe someone will find a solution for you.